# extracting object JSONArray

Tags: casting, indexing, arrays

Why does this syntax: SomeObject obj = ((SomeObject)JSONArray.get(i)) fail if the JSONArrya was created with only objects of type SomeObject?  SomeObject has greater complexity however it was created in loop and added to JSONArray, and never "flattened" and I just want to get it back a sub-segment.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure that i is starting at 0?  What error do you get?

Also you can't shove arbitrary objects into JSONArray only Boolean, JSONArray, JSONObject, Number, String, or the JSONObject.NULL object.

Answer (score 0):

Each element of the JSONArray was an object that contained an ArrayList of another object, simple enough.  The key was in finding JSONArray.toCollection(JSONArray,class) from there it was trivial.  HTH.